# My batch script bad counting occurrences of string in a file

Tags: string, batch-file

```
@echo off
set /a count = 0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%~1" /a:-d /b') do call :next "%%a" "%~2"
echo found %count% occurances of "%~2"
pause
GOTO:EOF
:next
set num=
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('find /c %2 ^< %1') do set num=%%b
set /a count=count+num
```

My code is wrong count of the text specified in the parameter. What's the problem?

Comment: I tried running this, it failed if I didn't match the case of the text, but worked fine otherwise.

Comment: If the specified sequence occurs several times in a row it counts as one.

Comment: `find` will count the number of lines that match your string, so searching xyyx' for 'x' will count as one, even though the x's aren't in a row.  If that's not what you want, you'll need a different tool.

Comment: @Mark - just post this as answer

Comment: In summary, it is impossible in batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark said, `find` return the number of *lines* that match in a file, not the number of individual strings in one line. To do so, you need to use another method, for example:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a count = 0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%~1" /a:-d /b') do (
   for /F "delims=" %%b in ('find %2 ^< "%%a"') do call :next "%%b" "%~2"
)
echo found %count% occurances of "%~2"
pause
GOTO:EOF

:next
set num=0
set "line=%~1"
:nextMatch
   set "line2=!line:*%~2=!"
   if "!line2!" equ "!line!" goto endMatchs
   set /A num+=1
   set "line=!line2!"
if defined line goto nextMatch
:endMatchs
set /a count=count+num
```

For example:

```
C:> type 1.txt
An example of text file.
This example line have two "example" words.
End of example.

C:> test 1.txt "example"
found 4 occurances of "example"
```

Comment: I think somewhere there is a mistake, script don't run. my_prog.bat "example" 1.txt

Comment: Try `my_prog.bat 1.txt "example"`

Comment: The same. If I type a string, which does not appear correctly returns 0, but I'll type something exist in file it returns an error that the command syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Awesome. I never thought that a seemingly simple script proves to be quite complicated. Excellent knowledge and skills, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`find` will count the number of lines that match your string, so searching 'xyyx' for 'x' will count as one match, even though the x's aren't in a row. If that's not what you want, you'll need a different tool.