# Batch File to Insert Row Numbers after Row Delimiters

Tags: batch-file, count, insert, edi, rownum

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance

I have an EDI file I receive from the state that has row delimiters of ~ and column delimiters of *

The file can have essentially any number of rows and columns, but it's in a particular order and has no row numbers. When I import it into a database, it doesn't import in order, and therefore I lose all meaning to the data imported. I'm trying to add an incremental count after each ~ followed by a column delimiter * {~#*}

if the file contains a line:

> ~ISA***~HL***~NM1***~NM1***

And the output I want it to have would look like:

> ~1*ISA***~2*HL***~3*NM1***~4*NM1***

I'm looking at Aacini's code from this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19796067/6935730

This seems so close to what I want it to do, but I'm not sure how to get it to insert (the number-th occurrence and * ) next to the string ( ~ ) for all files in a directory that have been updated since the last time the batch was ran. Specifically for, say, c:\whiskers\test.txt

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a count = 0
for /f "delims=" %%a in (dir "%~1" /a:-d /b') do (
   for /F "delims=" %%b in ('find %2 ^< "%%a"') do call :next "%%b" "%~2" )
echo found %count% occurrences of "%~2"
pause
GOTO:EOF
:next
set num=0
set "line=%~1"
:nextMatch
   set "line2=!line:*%~2=!"
   if "!line2!" equ "!line!" goto endMatchs
   set /A num+=1
   set "line=!line2!"
if defined line goto nextMatch
:endMatchs
set /a count=count+num
```

**::EDIT::**

This is a snippet from a file without being organized. I've replaced all *'s with pipes to make it appear normal in the post.

> ISA|00|          |00|          |ZZ|77045          |ZZ|100800
>   |16105|138|^|00501|006628|0|P|:~GS|HB|77045|10014800|2061005|1638|1519300|X|005X279A1~ST|271|157200|0051X2791~BHT|0022|11|1572|201005|16850~HL|1||20|1~NM1|PR|2|WA
>   State DSHS|||||PI|7745~PER|IC|WA State DSHS Provider
>   Relations|TE|800222~HL|2|1|21|1~NM1|1P|2|CENTER FOR HUMAN
>   SERVICES|||||XX|1053220~HL|3|2|2|0~TRN|2|575|91059822~NM1|IL|1|WASR|ERA||||MI|10182WA~REF|SY|2191128~REF|HJ|050526~REF|N6|ENG-ENGLISH~REF|18|130-WASHCAP
>   CENTRAL UNIT~REF|IF|042-KING NORTH
>   CSO~N3|CY|017-KING~DMG|D8|197215|F~DTP|291|RD8|20105-2016105~EB|1|IND|1^3^3^3^4^8^0^6^8^9^AL^MH^UC|MC|RAC=1105/BSP=CNP~REF|M7|01202~REF|6P|S01|6P
>   - ACES Coverage Group Code~DTP|291|RD8|201201-299931~MSG|This is the Client's eligibility as of this date, based on information available
>   at this
>   time~EB|A|IND|30|MC|RAC=105/BSP=CNP|||0~EB|B|IND|30|MC|RAC=115/BSP=CNP||0~EB|C|IND|30|MC|RAC=115/BSP=CNP||0~EB|MC|IND||HM~DTP|291|RD8|201301-299231~LS|210~NM1|Y2|2|King
>   County Behavioral Health Organization|||||PI|1050201~PER|IC|KING
>   COUNTY BEHAVIORAL HEALTH
>   ORGANIZATION|TE|8008049~LE|2120~EB|MC|IND||HM~DTP|291|RD8|20101-29991~LS|210~NM1|Y2|2|Coordinated
>   Care Healthy Options
>   Blind/Disabled|||||PI|201599904~PER|IC|COORDINATED CARE HEALTHY
>   OPTIONS
>   BLIND/DISABLED|TE|8776613~LE|21~HL|4|2|22|0~TRN|2|578|9149822~NM1|IL|1|BALIN-BAEY|MA|J|||MI|10080WA~REF|SY|53052~REF|HJ|004995~REF|N6|ENG-ENGLISH~REF|18|182-HCA
>   NORTHWEST~REF|IF|02-ALDERWOOD
>   CSO~N3|CY|031-SNOHOMISH~DMG|D8|1990|F~DTP|291|RD8|21005-201615~EB|1|IND|1^0^3^35^4^48^5^6^88^8^AL^MH^UC|MC|RAC=12/BSP=ABP~REF|6P|N05|6P
>   - ACES Coverage Group Code~REF|M7|02701~DTP|291|RD8|20001-29991~MSG|This is the Client's
>   eligibility as of this date, based on information available at this
>   time~EB|A|IND|30|MC|RAC=12/BSP=ABP|||0~EB|B|IND|30|MC|RAC=1201/BSP=ABP||0~EB|C|IND|30|MC|RAC=1201/BSP=ABP||0~EB|MC|IND||HM~DTP|291|RD8|20101-29991~LS|2120~NM1|Y2|2|North
>   Sound Admin Behavioral Health Organization|||||PI|105020901~

**This would be the data organized after separating by row. Ideally, it will have a row number followed by another pipe at the beginning of each line, but does not need to be spaced out into rows as it appears below.**

> ISA|00|          |00|          |ZZ|77045          |ZZ|100800
>   |16105|138|^|00501|006628|0|P|:
>   GS|HB|77045|10014800|2061005|1638|1519300|X|005X279A1
>   ST|271|157200|0051X2791   BHT|0022|11|1572|201005|16850   HL|1||20|1
>   NM1|PR|2|WA State DSHS|||||PI|7745   PER|IC|WA State DSHS Provider
>   Relations|TE|800222   HL|2|1|21|1   NM1|1P|2|CENTER FOR HUMAN
>   SERVICES|||||XX|1053220   HL|3|2|2|0   TRN|2|575|91059822
>   NM1|IL|1|WASR|ERA||||MI|10182WA   REF|SY|2191128   REF|HJ|050526
>   REF|N6|ENG-ENGLISH   REF|18|130-WASHCAP CENTRAL UNIT   REF|IF|042-KING
>   NORTH CSO   N3|CY|017-KING   DMG|D8|197215|F
>   DTP|291|RD8|20105-2016105
>   EB|1|IND|1^3^3^3^4^8^0^6^8^9^AL^MH^UC|MC|RAC=1105/BSP=CNP
>   REF|M7|01202   REF|6P|S01|6P - ACES Coverage Group Code
>   DTP|291|RD8|201201-299931   MSG|This is the Client's eligibility as of
>   this date, based on information available at this time
>   EB|A|IND|30|MC|RAC=105/BSP=CNP|||0   EB|B|IND|30|MC|RAC=115/BSP=CNP||0
>   EB|C|IND|30|MC|RAC=115/BSP=CNP||0   EB|MC|IND||HM
>   DTP|291|RD8|201301-299231   LS|210   NM1|Y2|2|King County Behavioral
>   Health Organization|||||PI|1050201   PER|IC|KING COUNTY BEHAVIORAL
>   HEALTH ORGANIZATION|TE|8008049   LE|2120   EB|MC|IND||HM
>   DTP|291|RD8|20101-29991   LS|210   NM1|Y2|2|Coordinated Care Healthy
>   Options Blind/Disabled|||||PI|201599904   PER|IC|COORDINATED CARE
>   HEALTHY OPTIONS BLIND/DISABLED|TE|8776613   LE|21   HL|4|2|22|0
>   TRN|2|578|9149822   NM1|IL|1|BALIN-BAEY|MA|J|||MI|10080WA
>   REF|SY|53052   REF|HJ|004995   REF|N6|ENG-ENGLISH   REF|18|182-HCA
>   NORTHWEST   REF|IF|02-ALDERWOOD CSO   N3|CY|031-SNOHOMISH
>   DMG|D8|1990|F   DTP|291|RD8|21005-201615
>   EB|1|IND|1^0^3^35^4^48^5^6^88^8^AL^MH^UC|MC|RAC=12/BSP=ABP
>   REF|6P|N05|6P - ACES Coverage Group Code   REF|M7|02701
>   DTP|291|RD8|20001-29991   MSG|This is the Client's eligibility as of
>   this date, based on information available at this time
>   EB|A|IND|30|MC|RAC=12/BSP=ABP|||0   EB|B|IND|30|MC|RAC=1201/BSP=ABP||0
>   EB|C|IND|30|MC|RAC=1201/BSP=ABP||0   EB|MC|IND||HM
>   DTP|291|RD8|20101-29991   LS|2120   NM1|Y2|2|North Sound Admin
>   Behavioral Health Organization|||||PI|105020901

Comment: Your examples seems to me that you want column numbers after each delimiter. Your question says you want row numbers.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that. I'd just look for the row delimiters and place in a count + a column delimiter. That way, it'll be a column in the final file when I import it. I can always manipulate the tables so long as there's a way to order them! :)

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
:: read filenames from source directory (raw files)
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.txt" '
 ) DO (
 REM if the filename exists in the destination, it's been processed
 IF NOT EXIST "%destdir%\%%a" (
  FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('type "%sourcedir%\%%a"') DO (
   SET /a linecount=0
   SET "line=%%b"
   SET "newline="
   CALL :process
  ) >"%destdir%\%%a"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF

:process
IF NOT DEFINED line ECHO %newline%&GOTO :EOF 
SET /a linecount+=1
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=~" %%r IN ("%line%") DO (
 SET "newline=%newline%~%linecount%*%%r"
 SET "line=%%s"
)
GOTO process
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

Sadly, you've provided scant explanation of your data. This process should work with the data you've presented, provided the output is less than ~8K. You don't say whether you data is really all in one line as input or you want one line of output (which is what this process will produce). If you want one line of output per logical input line, then small adjustments need to be made.

You haven't said how to determine whether the file has already been processed - it wouldn't be possible to be certain by analysing the data in the file since the apparent data content of an unprocessed and processed file may be identical.

I chose to keep the input data and output in separate directories. In that manner, all that is required is to see whether the file exists in both (has been processed) or only in the source (new). Hence `%%a` is set to each filename from the source in turn and if the file is not in the output directory, then process the file.

Processing is simple - assign the contents of the file to `line` then use `:process` to partition the line using the `~` and loop until there is no remaining line content.

As this is batch, it may show sensitivity to some symbols.

Comment: I apologize for not putting in a lot of description of the actual files I want it to go through --

Comment: So essentially, there are loops of information that can occur in the file:

Comment: The size of the file can vary widely, and there can be as many different rows in a single line as the line can fit. The first row has the delimiter at the end, and generally looks like this: ISA*21039*         *ZZ*       *1400801*ZZ~. Then the next 3 rows are also header information, but the gist of the file is that it has all the rows crammed into as many lines as can hold it. So the Batch file needs to read each line and spit it out with the additional #'s and *'s included after each ~ that it finds.

Comment: You'd need to post a representative sample of your input file. You say "as many "rows" in a single line - how long is the line? I have no idea what you mean by "header information" and whether or not you want such information reproduced or suppressed. Please edit into your question appropriate sample input and outputs.

Comment: Alright, on monday when I'm in the office I'll post a file I've edited to not include sensitive information.  Thank you for your patience and all your help!!!

Comment: Magoo, this works perfectly on the small test files that I've tried it on!... but it won't run the much larger files. Is there a way to make it process a file of indeterminate length?

Comment: Fundamentally, batch has a limit of ~8K on strings. If you could replace all `~` with newlines, then the process could be adjusted to suit, but effectively it would then be easier to use `findstr /n /v /r "." "filename_with_~_now_newlines"` which would produce lines formatted as `number : dataline`. This could be itself reprocessed by batch to `number*dataline` but not as one long `~`-separated string as it would exceed the 8K limit. Another possibility is using `sed` or `(g)awk` if you are open to 3rd-party non-propriety tools...